# Access to users Google Calendar events

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I have configured in my google account application following [CalDAV](https://developers.google.com/products/) and [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) instructions.

As result I have turned on 2 APIs for my application

- CalDAV API;
- Google Calendar API (GC API).

I have created token to get access via my personal client to google calendar information. Using [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java) I have loaded only my personal calendar events. I have investigated other java [samples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3) but I did not find how to load calendars of different users.

Is it possible to load someones calendar information via CalDAV\GC API with java client? Which clients information I should have got to load clients data (accept loginName)? Can I have a link to get more information about loading users' calendar events to view & manage its from external applications?

Answer (score 1):

To get the other users Calendar Events, Note: You must be an authenticated user that has a permission to access the other calendar events. By using this [`Events: list`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) you can try here to get the other users calendar event by passing the `calendarId` of the other user in the `calendarId` parameter.

There is a [Java example code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#examples) here that you can follow. The "**primary**" word here means that you will access your own calendar, just change it to the calendarId of the user to get its own calendar event.

If you want to list Google Calendar Events without the User Authentication, then this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117095/how-to-list-google-calendar-events-without-user-authentication) can help you with that. It use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to access the other user calendar.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i'have a questions:
<ul>
- how I can be authenticated as user who has a permission to access the other calendar events (i have to use my local application)?
- how i can know users `calendarId`? is it possible to load it in dynamic way (if i know users mail or login only)?
- is it possible to improve samples to resolve my issue?
</ul>
I have checked [calendar cmd sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-cmdline-sample) and [oauth2 cmd sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/oauth2-cmdline-sample)?

Comment: If i configured my application in google account (created `client_secrets.json` for registered project and APIs), how can I load here different users information if I use key for project connected to my account only? I red [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api) but its not clear for me...

Comment: Google provides [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java). I tried it with some suggested changes (changed `primary` to other users calendar):
---
        Events events = service.events()
          //      .list("primary")
                .list("i.vlasyuk@gmail.com")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
---
GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{"code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
...
  } ],
}

Comment: The user 'calendarId' is most likely his gmail account. If you are not authenticated to view the user calendar, then use the [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: `Service Account` needs `G Suite Domain` account. I do not have any dedicated domains for research google integration, so i can not register my personal `G Suite` account.

Comment: This other user must share the calendar with you if you want to be accessing it. Sharing is done either via the web interface or via the acl collection of the calendar API. Please check this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing